# Is there a good rule of thumb for regularization constants?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to train some linear logistic regression models and I need regularization. My models contain around 4000 features.

I know that without regularization, a good rule of thumb is to have 10x the number of data points as the number of features.

Unfortunately I have on the order of 1000 examples. With high regularization constants, I'm still able to achieve good results. I know that I could use cross validation for choosing these constants, but I will be training these models within the inner loop of a function, and I care less about accuracy than I do about just training the model once.

Right now, I've been trying constants on the order of num_features/num_instances, and this seems to work ok. But I have no reason to believe this is good. Is there some more principled way to determine regularization constants that is not cross-validation?

I'm using scikit learn, so in practice the constant is the inverse of what it is in the literature (for example, I'm using num_instances/num_features).

Answer (score 1):

Cross-validation is simple and easy to implement.  Rather than inventing something new, which might be dubious, I recommend you use cross-validation.  It works.

There are no formulas for the regularization constant, because it depends on the specific task you are trying to solve (i.e., it depends on the data).

Comment: I'm not choosing to not use cross validation because it's hard to implement. It's super simple. I know it works. I get it. I'm choosing not to use it because it has application specific drawbacks.

Comment: @Trevor, without knowing what those application specific drawbacks are, I'm not sure whether we can give you a useful answer.  Saying "give me a solution, but not cross-validation" does not make for a useful question, in my opinion.  For instance, any other solution might violate the same (unspecified) requirements that cross-validation violates.  I am also concerned about an XY problem if we don't know what the real requirements/constraints/goals are.

Comment: @Trevor, I have edited my answer to explain why there are unlikely to be anything of the form you wish for.